# PyTorch doubly stochastic normalisation of 3D tensor

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to implement double stochastic normalisation of an N x N x P tensor as described in Section 3.2 in [Gong, CVPR 2019](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/papers/Gong_Exploiting_Edge_Features_for_Graph_Neural_Networks_CVPR_2019_paper.pdf). This can be done easily in the N x N case using matrix operations but I am stuck with the 3D tensor case. What I have so far is

```
def doubly_stochastic_normalise(E):
    """E: n x n x f"""
    E = E / torch.sum(E, dim=1, keepdim=True)  # normalised across rows
    F = E / torch.sum(E, dim=0, keepdim=True)  # normalised across cols
    E = torch.einsum('ijp,kjp->ikp', E, F)
return E
```

but I'm wondering if there is a method without `einsum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this setting, you can always fall back to using [`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html) (batched matrix multiplication to be more precise). However, this requires you to transpose the axis. Recall the matrix multiplication for two 3D inputs, in einsum notation, it gives us:

```
bik,bkj->bij
```

Notice how the `k` dimension gets reduces. To get to this setting, we need to transpose the inputs of the operator. In your case we have:

```
ijp ? kjp -> ikp
 ↓     ↓      ↑
pij @ pjk -> pik
```

This translates to:

```
>>> (E.permute(2,0,1) @ F.permute(2,1,0)).permute(1,2,0)
#       ijp ➝ pij          kjp ➝ pjk      pik ➝ ikp
```

You can argue your method is not only shorter but also a lot more readable. I would therefore stick with [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html). The reason why the *einsum* operator is so useful here is because you can perform axes transpositions on the fly.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for an answer like this. Although einsum might be more readable, I think using basic tensor operations will be much faster computationally.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but you can always try and benchmark both methods!

Comment: To be honest I'm not too sure about how einsum is optimised so I always think that using basic operators should be faster. You're right about not being so sure, I ran some quick tests and there doesn't seem to be a significant speed up.

I ran both methods 1000 times each with dimensions 50 x 50 x 500 and the times were ~21.4s (einsum) and ~19.7s (permute then multiply).